# How resize a div height based on width with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, resize, scaling, aspect-ratio

while resizing `div` change  height based on width with **constraint ratio**

*@example* div `width:300` and `height:600` next Ill change width to `400` height change to `800` based on width

Comment: Are you talking just of the width and height attributes in the div element or are you wanting to do run time changes where the width/height may have been altered via CSS/JS settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the current width of the element and then reset its height.

Here's a simple example of doing that. It is using offsetWidth to get the current width, but depending on your use case that may or may not be good enough. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth

> Typically, offsetWidth is a measurement in pixels of the element's CSS width, including any borders, padding, and vertical scrollbars (if rendered). It does not include the width of pseudo-elements such as ::before or ::after. If the element is hidden (for example, by setting style.display on the element or one of its ancestors to "none"), then 0 is returned.

```js
// Function to set the height of an element proportional to its width
// el is the element we are interested in.
// ratio is the ratio of width to height that we want
function setHeight(el, ratio) {

// first we need to find out what the width of el currently is
  const w = el.offsetWidth; //this will always return an integer
  console.log(w);
  el.style.height = (w * ratio) + 'px';

//note you could also investigate getBoundingClientRect().width for a more general case when there have been transformations
}
```

```html
<div class="element" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: magenta;" onclick="setHeight(this, 600/300);">Click me</div>
```

offsetWidth always returns an integer, and of course there may have been some other calculations which make the width not an integer. Also what if there have been transformations? For a more comprehensive look at dimensions and what they mean see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect